# twilio - get detailed location of the number

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

In their example https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/search I can see the "Local" phone number location - City/ State. But $numbers variable do not contain any information about the city. Is there a way to get it as it was in the url?

```
$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local', array(
        "InRegion" => "AR"
    ));
```

Data:

```
object(sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator)[319]
  protected 'value' => 
    object(stdClass)[244]
      public 'friendly_name' => string '(646) 681-4092' (length=14)
      public 'phone_number' => string '+16466814092' (length=12)
      public 'lata' => string '132' (length=3)
      public 'rate_center' => string 'NWYRCYZN01' (length=10)
      public 'latitude' => string '40.714300' (length=9)
      public 'longitude' => string '-74.006000' (length=10)
      public 'region' => string 'NY' (length=2)
      public 'postal_code' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'iso_country' => string 'US' (length=2)
      public 'address_requirements' => string 'none' (length=4)
      public 'beta' => boolean false
      public 'capabilities' => 
        object(stdClass)[245]
          public 'voice' => boolean true
          public 'SMS' => boolean true
          public 'MMS' => boolean true
  protected 'escapingMethod' => string 'esc_specialchars' (length=16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The documentation shows the data you get back about a number resource. It can be different for different countries, here are the properties for [numbers in the US and Canada](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local-instance-properties) and below you can find the properties for numbers from other countries.

I believe, after testing a couple of numbers, that the city displayed in the phone number search page is actually the `rate_center` property.

If you need that to be more accurate, you might consider reverse geolocating the number based on the latitude and longitude returned from the API and getting the city from that. Or doing an address lookup based on the postal code.

Comment: Here in 2022, still doesn't look like we have a good way of tackling this. I'm hunting for similar functionality, but for existing numbers. The current `IncomingPhoneNumber` resource doesn't seem to have any regional (eg, `city`, `state`) information, though a new (and generally unavailable ) [Active Numbers API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/global-catalog/api/active-numbers) has solid information under `items.*.geography`...just a bummer that it's in a private dev preview.

Seems like this info should be accessible, as Twilio's own dashboard shows city/state on number index.